# Can Data access layer and business objects layer return observable collection?

Tags: .net, list, observablecollection, ilist

By Microsoft standards, Data Access Objects(DAO)...and Business Objects(BO) should return generic forms like IList instead of List.

But I need an ObservableCollection in Viewmodel and there is no IObservableCollection .

What should I do in this case ?

Can I return IList from BO to viewmodel and convert IList to ObservableCollection  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your collections *of*?

Let's say your service layer returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>`. Your root view model should have a property that's an `ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>`. So you're definitely going to need to have some code in your viewmodel to do this transformation, and at the same time you can populate an ObservableCollection instead of an IList or IEnumerable.

Comment: yes..i am able to convert it in viewmodel. I use some extension methods for same.

Comment: How can  I copy an observable collection using "Select" method

Comment: A select method gives you an IEnumerable. An observable collection can be given this IEnumerable in its constructor: `new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>(customers.Select(x=>ConvertCustomer(x)));`